# spring-security-oauth2 migration to spring-security 5 or above guide

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

As some classes or features are deprecated or removed from spring-security-oauth2 library, need to change those codes. But there seems no useful information for this migration. From source code got this https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide, but it's written in 2021, and no more demos or scripts showing how to migrate. And seems none other things can get from spring.io side. I googled things about it, but search results are all the like.
Could you please provide something valuable to do this?
Thanks in advance.

I'm using spring-boot 3.x, and read source code for migration information, searched things on google, switch lib and do everything I can, but things dont work still.
I'm expecting a useful migration guide from spring-security-oauth2 to spring-security 5.x or above, or a replacement for oauth2.

Comment: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials you won't find a migration guide, but you'll have everything you need to build your OAuth2 security conf with boot 3.1 / security 6.1

Comment: @ch4mp Thanks for your sharing, and as I read, need to assemble to make things work. Thanks anyway~